# String in my .Net MVC model returns null but a List returns fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For example in my model class

```
public class Dashboard
{
    public Dashboard(Account account)
    {
        AccountListName = new List<string>();
        AccountListName.Add(account.Name);

        string AccountName = account.Name;

    }
    public List<string> AccountListName { get; set; }

    public string AccountName { get; set; }

}
```

When I call the model in my controller.

```
var model = new DashBoard(account);
```

the model would contain the `AccountListName` properly but the `AccountName` would return null. Why does the AccountName returns null when I bind it to account.Name? Is there any weird interaction with the `string` type? And how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've redefined a more local scope of AccountName within your constructor that never assigns the value to your property.

```
string AccountName = account.Name;
```

Just remove the `string` and you should be fine. I'm surprised the compiler isn't warning you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But why doesn't the AccountListName also return null as well since I also redeclared it in my constructor?

Comment: You haven't declared it in your constructor. You've /instantiated/ it in your constructor.

Comment: You didn't re-declare it. You re-initialized it, since the auto property will initialize it for you, and then added your object to it.

Comment: `string foo;` This declared a variable `foo` of type string. `foo = "test";` This sets the variable to a value. `string foo = "test";` This declares AND sets the value. In the case of your list, you've declared AccountListName as a List<string> and AccountName as string by declaring them as properties. In your constructor you're using the AccountListName declaration by instantiating a new list and adding the name. You never use the AccountName property but rather created a new variable of the same name that immediately goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared AccountName a second time in the local scope of your function. You are setting this instead of the property of dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
this.AccountName = account.Name
```

instead of:

```
string AccountName = account.Name
```

You've accidentally redefined your `AccountName` to a local variable instead of assigning your property.

Comment: The `this` qualifier is redundant.

Comment: Lol no kidding. It makes it clearer to avoid issues such as these.

Comment: I will always choose clarity.

Comment: It is not clearer as the `this` is implied when using Property accessors within the scope of the class. It's bad practice to have both a property and scoped variable with the same name within the same class.

Comment: The scoped variable would not have "this". When you use "this", it's easier to:

Tell static and instance members apart. (And distinguish instance methods from delegates.)
Distinguish instance members from local variables and parameters (without using a naming convention)

Comment: Also its recommended if you follow Microsoft .Net Design Guidelines and Best Practices.

Comment: Using `this.` in front of class level members is generally accepted as a good practice to avoid confusion of scope. It's used a lot in Java programming but I rarely see it in C# everyday code. I cut my teeth without it and find it annoying to read but not enough to complain when I encounter it.

Comment: Following .Net Design Guidelines and Best Practices, inner-scoped variables should not be declared with names that begin with capital letters, thus alleviating any need for the `this`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Comment: how do you tell between static and instance members @JoeBrunscheon?

Comment: Settle down. Both of you are technically correct - it comes down to the style and complexity of the code. Personally my statics are usually in a settings class so my statics are obvious by their `Settings.NamedStaticMember` usage.

Comment: Right thats my whole point that its not wrong to have. IT IS PREFERENCE

Comment: That generally depends on institutional coding style guidelines. Microsoft guidelines don't differentiate between naming conventions of static and instance members, at which point using `this` would be a clear indication of an instance member vs a static member. Most coding style guidelines that I have seen at different companies generally break the MS naming conventions on this point and prefix member variables with something to differentiate them.